# Create invisibility cloak (alpha mask material)

Tags: rendering, materials, render-layers

How can I create an invisibility cloak? It should be an invisible object which causes other specified objects to become invisible when it covers those objects.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5104/2843

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading Leon Cheung's answer, I've redone my solution:

Say you have this setup

[image]

and you want to make the plane into an invisibility cloak that affects only the red monkey.

First, make the background transparent (see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1307/1112) for help).

For Blender Render, select the plane, and under the Materials tab of Properties window, enable `Transparency`, select `Mask` and set `Alpha` to zero:

[image]

For Cycles Render, select the plane and set its material to `Holdout`,

[image]

For both Blender and Cycles Render, you create two render layers: one with the invisibility cloak and objects affected by it, and one with the normal, unaffected objects.

Then create this node setup:

[image]

and the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Your own solution seems nice enough. For Cycles, I just want to share with a simple way, which needs just two renderlayers and less nodes:

- For the cloak object, you can use **Holdout** shader.
- For cases related to Z, you can simply add a **Z Combine** node (as you did in your own answer). Furthermore, **Alpha Over** brings more control on Alpha. Anyway, it could be one solution for Cycles. :)

[image]

**[Example File](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27373)**