# Object as transparent mask in Blender 2.8 Workbench engine

Tags: materials, 3d-view, transparency

I want to archive this effect:
[Create invisibility cloak alpha mask material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material)

But I can't find the option for transparent mask in the material tab in Blender 2.8's workbench engine. I can make the object transparent (by changing the alpha in its color settings), but then it will not mask other objects in scene. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This won't work in Blender Render but you can do this by rendering in OpenGL.   I'm still on Vers 2.77a but if you reduce the mask's opacity setting to 0.008, (no specular whatever)  it will be transparent and will also mask out any object behind it that's older than it is.   See here for details - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941

Comment: Thanks for reply but I still cant do it in Blender 2.8 since there is no transparency option in object material. I'll have to green screen it and compose in after effects.

Answer (score -1):

Material with Holdout Shader (in node editor: Shift A - Shaders - Holdout). Add that material to your blocking object.

Comment: The workbench engine doesn't have a *Holdout* shader, only Cycles has it in 2.80.