# Render objects without lights

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

Is it possible to bypass lights with a custom material/shader so that the material/shader is rendered directly to pixels? What I'm looking to do would have the renderer simply evaluate the scene and then have the material implicitly sent to pixels.

Cheers,

Comment: You can directly connect a color value to the shader output (without any node from the shader category). You may need to change the *Color Managment* to *Standard*, to get the exact color value. Not sure.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/totally-white-shadeless-material-in-cycles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/how-to-create-a-visible-material-that-does-not-emit-or-reflect-light/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131015/where-is-shadeless-material-option-for-blender-2-8/